# How to prove $P(A \cap B)-P(A).P(B)=P(A^c).P(B)-P(A^c \cap B)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I´ve been trying to prove this:
$P(A \cap B)-P(A).P(B)=P(A^c).P(B)-P(A^c \cap B)$
I know that if A and B are independent, then $P(A\cap B)=P(A).P(B)$
And if $A^c$ and $A$ are independent, then $P(A^C).P(B)=( A^c \cap  B)$
So, that equality is true if you take independent sets, but I don´t know which property could I use to prove the general case. I thought I could use $P(A | B)= P(A \cap B) / P(B) $ , but no idea how to apply it.

Comment: Perhaps it is easier to understand this as $P(A\cap B)+P(A^c\cap B)=(P(A)+P(A^c))P(B)$.

Comment: $B=(A \cap B) \cup (A^c \cap B)$

$P(B)= P(A \cap B) + P(A^c \cap B)$

$P(B).P(\Omega)=P(A \cap B) + P(A^c \cap B)$

$P(B).(P(A)+P(A^C))=P(A \cap B) + P(A^c \cap B)$

$P(A \cap B) - P(A).P(B)=P(A^C).P(B)-P(A^c \cap B) $
Am I right?

Comment: You are over thinking this.  What is $P(A\cap B) +P(A^c\cap B)$?  What is $P(A)+P(A^c)$?

Comment: The first one is P(B). The second one is P(omega)=1

Comment: Right.  So now look at my first comment.

Comment: I got it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:
These 2 sets are disjoint: $(A\cap B)$ and $(A^c\cap B)$. What is the sum of their probabilities?

Likewise: $A$ and $A^c$ are disjoint. What is the sum of their probabilities?

Comment: Hey thank you. I think I got the solution. I wrote it up here